# Excel - How to assign same group number for multiple occurrence of the same group name

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets. The 1st one has 2 columns. Group_id and Group_name. group_id column is empty in my 1st sheet and it also contains duplicate values. (i,e) duplicate group names.

The 2nd excel sheet contains contains all the group_id's and group_names. Unique values

There are almost 15,000 rows of group_id's and groups in my 1st excel sheet. Can you please help me with how to add the correct group_id in excel sheet 2 to excel sheet 1(contains duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

On Sheet1

In A2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"")
```

and then copy it down.

Comment: The formula follows your description. Have a sample data set as per your description and place the formula as suggested.

Comment: I tried pasting both in the same sheet. SAmple of my data..gid gname
1 MANO-D
2 23rd of September Communist League
3 Unknown
4 Black Nationalists
5 Tupamaros (Uruguay)
6 New Year's Gang
7 Weather Underground, Weathermen....And the 2nd table is MANO-D
23rd of September Communist League
Unknown
Unknown
Unknown
Black Nationalists
Tupamaros (Uruguay)
Unknown
New Year's Gang
New Year's Gang
Weather Underground, Weathermen..The 1st has group id and the 2nd one doesn't..I want group id in table 2..I tried lookup.. but it ain;t working..

Comment: If both the tables are on the same sheet, remove Sheet2! from the formula and change A:A with the column letter which has ID listed in it and replace B:B with the column letter which has gname in it.